# Can i pass null value in File(Android)

Tags: java, android, json, file, multipart

I am working with volley and i send a image(File) to database through API. When i pass a image in File variable it's working but if i don't want to send any image it's not working, my question is can i pass Null value or empty in File if yes then how??

```
protected String doInBackground(Boolean... booleen) 
{
   UserApi userApi = new UserApi();
   String result = null;
   try 
      {
        final File image = null;
        result = userapi.register(name, email, password, image);
       } catch (ApiException e) 
       {
            e.printStackTrace();
       } 
        catch (JSONException e) 
       {
            e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

Please tell how i can solve it?